# Forge ARKit - Navisworks to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge, autodesk-navisworks, autodesk-arvr

I'm testing the Model Derivative API to translate one of my Navisworks files to SVF and then using the [Forge AR|VR Toolkit](http://forgetoolkit.com/#/) to load the model in Unity. I tried before with some of the [sample models](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/navisworks-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Navisworks/files/GUID-C3AF0000-2810-47FB-BF21-95181A36DCD8-htm.html) in Navisworks and they loaded correctly to Unity.

When I try to load my own Navisworks file it only loads some of the components without throwing any message in the unity console, just the "loaded in: 115.9605317" one:
[image]

In the Forge Viewer, after I translated the model to SVF, it looks like this:
[image]

My manifest got these errors:

```
{
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1tZXJzaWFfdGVzdHMvVEFJRi1TVFAtMzAtQ0RNLTMxMDAxX1RpbWVsaW5lci5ud2Q",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "hasThumbnail": "true",
            "children": [
                {
                    "guid": "8181cbda-7e23-4809-a45a-08d2499ce6a7",
                    "type": "geometry",
                    "role": "3d",
                    "name": "TAIF-STP-30-CDM-31001.nwc",
                    "status": "success",
                    "hasThumbnail": "true",
                    "progress": "complete",
                    "messages": [
                        {
                            "type": "warning",
                            "code": "Navisworks-MissingXref",
                            "message": [
                                "Missing external reference file: {0}",
                                "C:\\Users\\arq5\\Documents\\00-RVT-RECURSOS\\05-TEXTURASJPG\\HORMIGON\\hormigon ocre.jpg"
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "viewableID": "cache",
                    "useAsDefault": true,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "guid": "49aef14e-066f-4cfc-b5ac-9c325b4d90b6",
                            "type": "view",
                            "role": "3d",
                            "name": "Default",
                            "status": "success",
                            "camera": [
                                2217718.25,
                                7836792,
                                4384.18896484375,
                                2217845,
                                7836792,
                                4325.51806640625,
                                0.42008858919143677,
                                -7.63888952093339e-13,
                                0.9074831008911133,
                                3.273224115371704,
                                1.5807563066482544,
                                1,
                                0
                            ],
                            "useAsDefault": true,
                            "hasThumbnail": "true",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1tZXJzaWFfdGVzdHMvVEFJRi1TVFAtMzAtQ0RNLTMxMDAxX1RpbWVsaW5lci5ud2Q/output/0/0_100.png",
                                    "role": "thumbnail",
                                    "mime": "image/png",
                                    "guid": "f6fa8a98-f6bc-4efd-a2a0-f3e3400f0cba",
                                    "type": "resource",
                                    "resolution": [
                                        100,
                                        100
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1tZXJzaWFfdGVzdHMvVEFJRi1TVFAtMzAtQ0RNLTMxMDAxX1RpbWVsaW5lci5ud2Q/output/0/0_200.png",
                                    "role": "thumbnail",
                                    "mime": "image/png",
                                    "guid": "128b27ba-07e8-4696-abbf-518500d081c8",
                                    "type": "resource",
                                    "resolution": [
                                        200,
                                        200
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1tZXJzaWFfdGVzdHMvVEFJRi1TVFAtMzAtQ0RNLTMxMDAxX1RpbWVsaW5lci5ud2Q/output/0/0_400.png",
                                    "role": "thumbnail",
                                    "mime": "image/png",
                                    "guid": "a47779a5-a149-4d27-b80e-84dd78bf28cb",
                                    "type": "resource",
                                    "resolution": [
                                        400,
                                        400
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "guid": "64bc3028-731c-4ea1-9775-7a1e1a89ec82",
                            "type": "folder",
                            "name": "3D View",
                            "role": "viewable",
                            "hasThumbnail": "false",
                            "status": "success",
                            "progress": "0% complete",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "guid": "1f08519e-1628-4839-af45-93b200032b26",
                                    "type": "view",
                                    "role": "3d",
                                    "name": "{3D}",
                                    "camera": [
                                        2217922,
                                        7836688.5,
                                        4324.17578125,
                                        2217995,
                                        7836701.5,
                                        4376.45751953125,
                                        -0.5683003664016724,
                                        -0.10182362794876099,
                                        0.8164966106414795,
                                        1,
                                        45,
                                        224.16700744628906,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "status": "success"
                                },
                                {
                                    "guid": "3e259277-489f-4e98-8ed8-3b3e0a49fd75",
                                    "type": "view",
                                    "role": "3d",
                                    "name": "Analytical",
                                    "camera": [
                                        2218373.25,
                                        7836174,
                                        4628.72900390625,
                                        2218286.25,
                                        7836905.5,
                                        4197.9208984375,
                                        -0.05953280255198479,
                                        0.5012193918228149,
                                        0.8632699251174927,
                                        1,
                                        45,
                                        1036.07373046875,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "status": "success"
                                },
                                {
                                    "guid": "ef039511-0489-446e-8c06-78bcc5ea0ab2",
                                    "type": "view",
                                    "role": "3d",
                                    "name": "{3D - carmen.gg2}",
                                    "camera": [
                                        2217942,
                                        7836805.5,
                                        4334.80078125,
                                        2217918.5,
                                        7836822,
                                        4309.9580078125,
                                        -0.5310993790626526,
                                        0.37772226333618164,
                                        0.7584585547447205,
                                        1,
                                        45,
                                        486.9418640136719,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "status": "success"
                                },
                                {
                                    "guid": "3e93f0b5-97db-430e-9189-a120e8e402c3",
                                    "type": "view",
                                    "role": "3d",
                                    "name": "{3D - carmen.gg2} Copy 1",
                                    "camera": [
                                        2218071.75,
                                        7836715.5,
                                        4252.97412109375,
                                        2218091.5,
                                        7836931.5,
                                        4262.3193359375,
                                        -0.004109169356524944,
                                        -0.04292852059006691,
                                        0.9990696907043457,
                                        1,
                                        45,
                                        567.1892700195312,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "status": "success"
                                },
                                {
                                    "guid": "5fa9f6b6-0847-44b6-b6d9-595c1e772d89",
                                    "type": "view",
                                    "role": "3d",
                                    "name": "{3D - ricardo.navas}",
                                    "camera": [
                                        2217873.75,
                                        7837036,
                                        4360.271484375,
                                        2217985.25,
                                        7836975,
                                        4267.619140625,
                                        0.5160266160964966,
                                        -0.2839450240135193,
                                        0.8081409335136414,
                                        1,
                                        45,
                                        835.2225952148438,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "status": "success"
                                },
                                {
                                    "guid": "3f044262-ed05-4336-903b-43df445f204f",
                                    "type": "view",
                                    "role": "3d",
                                    "name": "{3D - carmen.gg2} Copy 1 Copy 1",
                                    "camera": [
                                        2218292.75,
                                        7836805.5,
                                        4375.10009765625,
                                        2218032.75,
                                        7836986.5,
                                        4314.8154296875,
                                        -0.1535138338804245,
                                        0.10686176270246506,
                                        0.9823513031005859,
                                        1,
                                        45,
                                        876.185791015625,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "status": "success"
                                },
                                {
                                    "guid": "8dc04e9c-6994-48d5-be18-5efe1c48c675",
                                    "type": "view",
                                    "role": "3d",
                                    "name": "{3D - jorge.mansoGPHPF}",
                                    "camera": [
                                        2218281,
                                        7836987.5,
                                        4511.279296875,
                                        2218000.25,
                                        7836937,
                                        4309.6044921875,
                                        -0.5683003664016724,
                                        -0.10182362794876099,
                                        0.8164966106414795,
                                        1,
                                        45,
                                        713.5865478515625,
                                        1
                                    ],
                                    "status": "success"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "guid": "7c3a22f2-fe30-4bf9-84ef-86fe9b2f9544",
                            "type": "view",
                            "role": "3d",
                            "name": "Vista",
                            "camera": [
                                2218147,
                                7836836.5,
                                4338.59912109375,
                                2218120.75,
                                7836927.5,
                                4315.5693359375,
                                -0.06565795093774796,
                                0.22708940505981445,
                                0.9716581106185913,
                                2.7923386096954346,
                                0.785398006439209,
                                1,
                                0
                            ],
                            "status": "success"
                        },
                        {
                            "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1tZXJzaWFfdGVzdHMvVEFJRi1TVFAtMzAtQ0RNLTMxMDAxX1RpbWVsaW5lci5ud2Q/output/0/0.svf",
                            "role": "graphics",
                            "mime": "application/autodesk-svf",
                            "guid": "9b21a9ef-8aef-4c8a-821d-e5c614446cae",
                            "type": "resource"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1tZXJzaWFfdGVzdHMvVEFJRi1TVFAtMzAtQ0RNLTMxMDAxX1RpbWVsaW5lci5ud2Q/output/0/properties.db",
                    "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
                    "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
                    "guid": "8e4c0271-e625-4b69-8662-562f34b79158",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "status": "success"
                }
            ],
            "name": "TAIF-STP-30-CDM-31001_Timeliner.nwd",
            "progress": "complete",
            "outputType": "svf",
            "status": "success"
        },
        {
            "status": "success",
            "outputType": "arkit",
            "children": [
                {
                    "view_id": "8181cbda-7e23-4809-a45a-08d2499ce6a7",
                    "status": "success",
                    "startTime": "2021-04-09T09:43:43.372Z",
                    "endTime": "2021-04-09T10:40:55.076Z",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "name": "navisworks"
                },
                {
                    "view_id": "8181cbda-7e23-4809-a45a-08d2499ce6a7",
                    "status": "success",
                    "startTime": "2021-04-13T07:14:05.130Z",
                    "endTime": "2021-04-13T08:11:55.941Z",
                    "type": "resource",
                    "name": "taif"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "success"
}
```

What could be causing this? maybe the missing texture? the "0% complete" in the "3d View" node of the manifest?

OP EDIT:
Just found out something interesting. Most of the meshes are loaded in a random coordinate. Just the last 2 items are in 0,0,0 coordinate (first picture). Also those 2 items aren't in the correct scale.
[image]

After moving models closer to origin in Navisworks file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've seen a similar problem in the past where the geometry coming to Unity was so far from the origin that it just didn't show up at all. You could try:

- updating the original Navisworks file to move the model closer to origin, or
- modifying the position of all the geometries loaded to Unity to move them closer to origin

Comment: Updating original navisworks file improves some of the models. I added a new screenshot to op. But some of the parts just instantiates at 0,0,0 such as the floor in the screenshot. I checked those parts in the navisworks file and they are in the correct place.